Build failed: Video thumbnail build error when launching video trimmer and video editor in flutter
video trimmer and video editor are giving me errors on launch as below:
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':video_thumbnail'.


Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Failed to query the value of property 'buildFlowServiceProperty'.


Could not isolate value org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.BuildFlowService$Parameters_Decorated@6d07c214 of type BuildFlowService.Parameters
A problem occurred configuring project ':video_thumbnail'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
> Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

       If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I tried adding the ffmpeg kit package but it still did not work
